# Difference between xx[:,9] and xx[:][9]?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to understand the difference between the notations below.

```
print(np.min(xx[:,9]))
print(np.min(xx[:][9]))
```

```
0.015971377798342325
-0.7342680230504756
```

Why the results are different?

Comment: Try printing `xx[:,9`]` and `xx[:][9]` that should give you an idea of what is happening

Comment: @fmarm Wow. They have very different meaning! I understand `xx[:,9]`, but `xx[:][9]` looks more complicated.

Comment: With arrays, `xx[:]` does virtually nothing.  Each `[]` index is evaluated separately.

Comment: @hpaulj oh, I see, `xx[:]` is nothing in arrays! I will keep that in mind! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different.
Consider this example :

```
>>> arr = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> arr[:,1]
array([2,2,2])
```

Here you are slicing in 2 dimensions, you are selection 2nd column of all the three rows. For our reference let us call this as **combined slicing**.

In second case :

```
>>> arr = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
>>> arr[:][1]
array([1,2,3])
```

In this example, the 2 slices are not combined, it simply means execute the first slice operation and then execute second slice operation on the result of 1st. Here  slice operations are **not combined**. So, here `arr[:]` is executed first. `[:]` does nothing, its like slice from first to last, so the result is the same array. Second `[1]` gets executed, so its like grabbing the second row based on its index.

Hope you got the difference.

**Why Results are different ??**
In first case you are printing the minimum of 9th column of all the rows.
In second case you are printing the minumum of 9th row itself, why? see the above explanation.